# Is there Android native library for displaying charts/graphs?

Tags: android, graph, charts

I want to know, is there Android native library for displaying charts and graph.

I know there is third-party like GraphView, WilliamChart and Hello Charts, but I found Google Adwords android app that have charts, and want to know does Google developed their own library or no.

All posts that I found is too old like 1-4 years.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that "Android native library" means "part of the Android SDK".

In that case, no, there is no charting and graphing library, akin to the third-party ones that you listed, in the Android SDK.

> want to know does Google developed their own library or no

It is entirely possible that Google developed their own charting and graphing library. It is not part of the Android SDK, at least at this time, and I am not aware that they released it as their own library (open source or otherwise).